# How to serialize and deserialize json in c #

Tags: c#, algorithm, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am using an API that returns json data. I have found Newtonsoft JSON, but I didn't find docs for how to use.

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Comment: If you click on the `json.net` tag that you used it will take you to the many, many posts here related to it where you can study some of them and learn almost everything you need to get started.

Comment: If you open "Manage Nuget Packages" for your project, you'll see that it's "Newtonsoft.Json".  If you use that to search the internet (removing the "dot" to reduce confusion, i.e., searching for "Newtonsoft Json"), you will likely find https://www.newtonsoft.com/json as the first hit.  All the docs you need are there.  It really helps to spell something correctly (or close to correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For syntax and documentation go [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

This is is a variation of what I used in a school project

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static string ConvertObjectToJson<T>(T Ls)
{
    if (Ls == null)
        return null;

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ls);
}

public static T JasonConvertToObj<T>(string JsonStr , T FalseReturn)
{
    try
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonStr);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string erorstr = e.Message;
        return FalseReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's *Systex*?